# How to show different searchResultsController in UISearchController

Tags: swift, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller, uisearchbardelegate, uisearchresultscontroller

I am using `UISearchController` (not `UISearchDisplayController`), i wanted to show a separate view when search is active. I dont want to use the current view.

Tried with `self.searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: self.resultsController )`. But this doesn't show anything.

Even tried this

```
 func presentSearchController(_ searchController: UISearchController) {
     DispatchQueue.main.async {
         searchController.searchResultsController?.view.isHidden = false
     }
 }

 func didPresentSearchController(_ searchController: UISearchController) {
     searchController.searchResultsController?.view.isHidden = false
 }
```

My default table data before search is active is as below, i want this table to hide and show separate view and pass the typed keyword to that new view. How can i achieve this?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As there is no direct segue to viewController, we need to explicitly refer the viewController we wanted to use.

I have used the below code and it loads my new controller when my searchBar is active.

```
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    self.resultsController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "searchResults") as! SearchResultsTableViewController
    self.searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: self.resultsController )
```

Let me know if any better approach is available.